# How to prevent Gradle from including the resource files in the JAR

Tags: java, spring, compilation, gradle, applicationcontext

I'm using spring so I have ApplicationContext.xml file in the resources directory. I know that by default the 'build' task of Gradle include all the resource files in the JAR file it creates.

Now, I wish to edit or replace the ApplicationContext.xml depends on the machine I'm running my application (development or production). It's not intuitive to build a script to do it when it's in the JAR.

I would like it if the 'build' would put the resource files in the same folder as the JAR files but not in them. is that possible?
is there another approach I should take to overcome this issue?

Comment: Don't… You don't want to  move around different deployable artifacts. Add a production context and override in another file what you don't need or need different in your test environment. Then use Spring Profiles to load the correct files.

Comment: You should probably using Spring's profile support to conditionally include configuration and beans rather than subverting Gradle's resource processing

Comment: Thanks, that's seems like the right approach to the issue. I felt I was going the wrong way.

Comment: Have you explored, jar.doFirst { exclude 'src/main/resources/xxx.xml' }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent files from being added to the output jar like this:

```
jar{
    exclude 'applicationContext.xml'
}
```